# Why is Express HTTP server downloading the res.end() from my localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm following the [Nodejs tutorial from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment) and created a basic HTTP server using Express.

Normally, when I navigate to the http://127.0.0.1:8000, the web page should show 'Hello World'. But, with this code, a file with the string from the `res.end()` method downloads on my PC.

The `hellonode.js` file:

```
const http = require('http');

const PORT = 8000;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'plain/text'
    });

    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(PORT);

console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}/`);
```

I'm running the code using the command `nodemon hellonode.js`. Why is that happening?

Comment: `text/plain`, not `plain/text`

Comment: Hint `'Content-Type': 'plain/text'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Content-Type` of the response is what determines the browser's behavior. When the `Content-Type` matches `text/plain`, your browser will simply display the text in the window as you expect.

However, you are currently setting the `Content-Type` as `plain/text`, which the browser does not recognize. Because the browser does not have a default behavior for responses of this unrecognized type, it is downloading the response as a file.